# How to convert int data to km/h?

Tags: c

i have a sensor

The datasheet says you can divide the data from the sensor by 100 to get the data you want.
And for example, 0xff97 is -1.05km/h

How does 0xff97 become -1.05 km/h?

Comment: First of all, if you take that hexadecimal value and display it as a (signed) decimal value, what is that?

Comment: thank you so much for the quick replies
I'll study it a little deeper, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xFF97` is `-105` in 16-bit [two's complement integer representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

If you divide that number by `100`, then you get `-1.05 km/h`.